# Laravel sanctum не проходит аутентефикацию

Tags: laravel, vue-cli, laravel-8, sanctum

Composer.json:

```
    "require": {
        "ext-json": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.12.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.9",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.18"
    },
```

Kernel.php:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
      'web' => [
        EncryptCookies::class,
        AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        StartSession::class,
        AuthenticateSession::class,
        // ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        SubstituteBindings::class,
      ],

      'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        SubstituteBindings::class,
      ],
    ];
```

Cors.php:

```
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*, /login'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

sanctum.php:

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', implode(',', [
      'localhost',
      'localhost:8000',
      'localhost:8080',
      'localhost:8002',
      '127.0.0.1:8002',
      '127.0.0.1:8080',
    ]))),
```

auth.php:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
        Route::prefix('api/v1')
          ->middleware('auth:sanctum')
          ->group(function() {
              require_once base_path('routes/Api/V1/Auth/routes.php');
              require_once base_path('routes/Api/V1/Users/routes.php');
          });
```

Axios:

```
import Vue, { PluginObject } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const config = {};

const _axios = axios.create(config);

_axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
_axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

_axios.interceptors.request.use(
  cfg => {
    return cfg;
  },
  err => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  },
);

/**
 * Add a response interceptor
 */
_axios.interceptors.response.use(
  res => {
    return res;
  },
  err => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  },
);

const Plugin: PluginObject<any> = {
  install: Vue => {
    Vue.$axios = _axios;
  },
};
Plugin.install = Vue => {
  Vue.$axios = _axios;
  window.axios = _axios;
  Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $axios: {
      get() {
        return _axios;
      },
    },
  });
};

Vue.use(Plugin);

export default Plugin;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логинюсь. Но любой запрос через `auth:sanctum`:

```
{message: "Unauthenticated."}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ошибки

Ошибки было две:

- не для всех роутов был прописан `middleware('api')`;
- Не корректно указаны `middleware`.

---

### Решение

У меня роуты разделены в `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, и для каждого роута я устанавливал `middleware` так:

```
Route::prefix('api/v1')
  ->middleware('api')
  ->middleware('auth:sanctum')
  ->group(function() {
    require_once base_path('routes/Api/V1/{some path}/routes.php');
    require_once base_path('routes/Api/V1/{some path}/routes.php');
  })
```

Что как оказалось не работает в **laravel 8**.

Корректно для меня заработало тогда, когда я передал массив `middleware`. Причём,  важен порядок `middleware` в этом массиве.

```php
Route::prefix('api/v1')
  ->middleware(['api', 'auth:sanctum'])
  ->group(function() {
    require_once base_path('routes/Api/V1/{some path}/routes.php');
  });

Route::prefix('api/v1')
  ->middleware(['api', 'auth:sanctum'])
  ->group(function() {
    require_once base_path('routes/Api/V1/{some path}/routes.php');
  });

Route::prefix('api/v1')
  ->middleware(['api', 'auth:sanctum'])
  ->group(function() {
    require_once base_path('routes/Api/V1/{some path}/routes.php');
    require_once base_path('routes/Api/V1/{some path}/routes.php');
  });
```